# error installing angular cli how can i fix it?

Tags: npm, angular-cli, npm-install

When I run the command  `npm install -g @angular/cli`, I  get this error.

```
λ npm install -g @angular/cli
npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/
npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pickAlgorithm')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rossd\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-27T16_56_57_347Z-debug.log
```

How can I solve this?

My npm v is 8.1.0.
My node v is v16.13.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like what you need is to update your node js version, which then will also update your npm and LTS version, as it says in [this article](https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/), hope it help you!.

I'm currently working on angular 8 and I'm using npm v 7.11.2 and my node js v is 14.15.1.

Comment: i have the node and npm version update already

Comment: How about downgrade?

Comment: how could i do that ?

Comment: First of all, its not a proved solution, but I do can use angular on my node js version so that could help.

Then to do this 'downgrade' what you have to do is to uninstall node first, for that you have to :

1.Open the Windows Control Panel.
2.Choose the Programs and Features option.
3.Click the “Uninstall a program”
4.Select Node. js, and click the Uninstall link.
And then just download and install the version that you want